# How to change css position left to right using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div with `left` value i wanted to change it to `right` side with values

```
#check
{
    left:50px;
    top:20px;
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:rgb(100,200,0);
}
```

So i tried jquery like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#check').css('right','20px');

});
```

is this possible?.i tried searching but all are with the same attribute different value changes.
[Here is the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwX8Z/1/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to set `left` to default, and the value for `right`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#check').css({
  'right':'20px',
  'left': 'auto'
 });

});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwX8Z/4/) thanks to [MackieeE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/292735/mackieee)

Comment: From this i think we can set values for both attribute left and right. am i right? @Mark

Comment: Indeed, important part is the 'auto' value to reset the value as being not set. This will work for left an right, not top and bottom because of position relative and not absolute.
@MackieeE: thanks

Comment: okay i got about 50% clear.idea is good but i can't understand why this is not possible for top and bottom in regarding to position. Thanks

Comment: When you change your position to absolute, it will be, but then you need a wrapper/container that is position relative

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#check').css({'right':'20px'});    
});
```

Comment: this is the same as OP writing thats causing the issue, with another syntax of writing, this does not address the issue itself changing the left to right

Answer (score 1):

You will need to remove the left then set the right.

For example:

```
$('#check').css('right', '20px').css('left', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

simply as it :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#check').css('left','auto').css('right','20px');

 });
```

example : http://jsfiddle.net/mwX8Z/5/

Comment: while the left role exist it overiding the right role so set the left role to auto

Comment: pay attention of you'r relative position is not responding on left right roles so try this fiddel with absolute positions : http://jsfiddle.net/mwX8Z/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#check {
    left: 50px;
    top:20px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:rgb(100, 200, 0);
}
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#check').css({
        'left': 'auto',
        'right': '20px'
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p3nTG/)

Answer (score -1):

found something very interesting. To animate something to the right do something like:

```
$(".something").animate({
 left:"",
 right:"",
 marginRight:"10px"
},300);
```

This is like setting it to right: 10px;